# How to remove FacesMessages from the FacesContext?

Tags: jsf

In my screen, I have a drop down(select box), on selection of any of the options in that drop down , i display one or more text boxes beside the select box using javascript/css - display:none and display:block. All these input controls are in the same jsf form. Each of the input controls have their own validator. The problem is suppose the user selects *option1* from selection box and doesn't input value or inputs a wrong value for *inputbox1,* i add a custom FacesMessage in the Validator and is shown appropriately and suppose the user selects the *option2* the second time and inputs the wrong value for the *inputbox2* then another FacesMessage is added in the validator. But **Now both the Messages are shown - means - the message for inputbox1 and inputbox2 - which is wrong** My assumption is that , this happens because they exist in the same form and their instances are not destroyed yet in the FacesContext and in the UIView. I decided to delete the messages this way

```
Iterator<FacesMessage> msgIterator = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessages();
    while(msgIterator.hasNext())
    {
        msgIterator.next();
        msgIterator.remove();
    }
```

But this sometimes gives java.util.NoSuchElementException org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlMessagesRendererBase$MessagesIterator.next

So 2 questions :

1) What is the problem in deleting the FacesMessages this way? I am using myfaces-api-1.2.3.jar and myfaces-impl-1.2.3.jar

2) Is there a better approach to handle my scenario? I only want to show relevent messages every time a jsf request is processed

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not that I wasn't able to delete the messages from the FacesContext. The problem was that everytime the form was submitted there were few input controls (which were not displayed using display:none )which retained some values () and so the Validators and Backing Bean code added the FacesMessages for those non-visible input controls in the FacesContext. Now, everytime the select option was changed, i cleared the other form fields which were not necessary and so the messages are not added.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell this is not enough, since in

```
org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImpl
```

(version: 2.0.15, revision: 1364593), there are 2 lists of messages (`_orderedMessages` and `_messages`) and your method only clears `_orderedMessages`.

To clear `_messages` do this:

```
Iterator<String> itIds = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getClientIdsWithMessages();
while (itIds.hasNext()) {
    List<FacesMessage> messageList = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessageList(itIds.next());
    if (!messageList.isEmpty()) { // if empty, it will be unmodifiable and throw UnsupportedOperationException...
        messageList.clear();
    }
}
```

Please also note that this is very fragile since it relies on implementation details, but I could not find a better way :(

Comment: It also throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` even though the list is not empty, in JSF2.0 (Mojarra).

Answer (score 1):

I don't use MyFaces, so I can't go in detail about this, but in the Sun RI (Mojarra) the bug of unremoveable facesmessages was been fixed in version 1.2_07 about 1.5 years ago.

So to achieve what you want, try upgrading MyFaces to the latest available (they might have fixed the same bug as well) or replacing by [Mojarra](https://javaserverfaces.github.io/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was not that I wasn't able to delete the messages from the FacesContext. The problem was that everytime the form was submitted there were few input controls (which were not displayed using display:none )which retained some values () and so the Validators and Backing Bean code added the FacesMessages for those non-visible input controls in the FacesContext. Now, everytime the select option was changed, i cleared the other form fields which were not necessary and so the messages are not added. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Iterator<FacesMessage> it = context.getMessages();
while ( it.hasNext() ) {
    it.next();
    it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessages() != null) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessages().remove();
    }
```

Comment: This causes JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught during processing of INVOKE_APPLICATION