# Deleting FacesMessage from FacesContext

Tags: jsf

I add FacesMessages in this way

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(severity, message, null));
```

I try to remove them in this way

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
Iterator<FacesMessage> it = context.getMessages();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    FacesMessage message = it.next();
    if (message.getSeverity() == FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN) {
            it.remove();
    }

}
```

The problem that this iterator is always empty and the messages are accumulated and displayed many times. I am also aware of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919132/how-to-remove-facesmessages-from-the-facescontext)

Comment: Faces messages are request scoped and as such they live only for a single request/response cycle. What is the need to remove them manually?

Comment: Looks like just a timing problem. When and where exactly are you trying to remove them? This information is nowhere visible in the question and therefore no one in the world would be able to reproduce your problem on a blank project. Let me guess, are you trying to remove them *after* render response? Does it work if the code is (for testing purposes) placed directly after the `addMessage()`?

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for clearing that the messages are request scoped. I already solved this issue. It was a timing problem as you both suggested

Comment: OK, I'll post an answer. It'd however have been better if you actually edited the question to include details about when and where exactly you tried to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

The iterator will be empty when the faces messages are already rendered. That will in turn happen when the render response phase has already taken place. This in turn suggests that you were trying to remove it *after* the render response phase. For example, inside a `PhaseListener` which is hooked on `afterPhase()` of `PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE`.

One solution would be moving the job to the `beforePhase()`.