# how to show same message for two validators without duplicate JSF

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

I have two validators for two different inputs, like that

```
<ui:include src="/validators/appSpecSubEntityDuplicateValidator.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="id" value="disbursementPaymentScheduledDateDuplicateValidator"/>
    <ui:param name="entityList" value="#{grantData.mainEntity.grantDisbursements}"/>
    <ui:param name="tempHolder" value="#{grantDisbursementSubForm.entity}"/>
    <ui:param name="fieldsList" value="#{['paymentScheduledDate']}"/>
    <ui:param name="isNew" value="#{grantDisbursementSubForm.isNew()}"/>
    <ui:param name="message" value="This Disbursement already exist."/>
    <ui:param name="process" value="#{not empty param[grantDisbursementSaveButton.clientId]}"/>
</ui:include>

<ui:include src="/validators/appSpecSubEntityDuplicateValidator.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="id" value="disbursementPaymentNumberDuplicateValidator"/>
    <ui:param name="entityList" value="#{grantData.mainEntity.grantDisbursements}"/>
    <ui:param name="tempHolder" value="#{grantDisbursementSubForm.entity}"/>
    <ui:param name="fieldsList" value="#{['paymentNumber']}"/>
    <ui:param name="isNew" value="#{grantDisbursementSubForm.isNew()}"/>
    <ui:param name="message" value="This Disbursement already exist."/>
    <ui:param name="process" value="#{not empty param[grantDisbursementSaveButton.clientId]}"/>
</ui:include>
```

When two inputs both incorrect, it appear two messages with same text.
I want to show **only one**. Help me, please...  Thanks!

Comment: Please post some code?

Comment: I already post code

Comment: I know there is a duplicate question with an answer by @BalusC about this in Stackoverflow. I just do not seem able to find it.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will try to find it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919132/how-to-remove-facesmessages-from-the-facescontext (not a full duplicate, but close enough I think... to get you started)